# Database query throws KotlinNullPointerException while trying get LiveData

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, android-room, dao

I am trying to create room database in kotlin/android but I am getting `KotlinNullPointerException` when I try te get LiveData from the database. I have two tables `Car` and `Refueling` and from one fragment I can get `Car` data without any problems but in a second fragment, I get errors while trying to get `Refueling` LiveData. I couldn't find any differences between these two fragments/DAO. Below is a simplified code.

**Refueling data class:**

```
@Entity(tableName = "refueling_table", foreignKeys = [ForeignKey(entity = Car::class,
    parentColumns = arrayOf("carID"),
    childColumns = arrayOf("carID"),
    onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE)]
)
data class Refueling(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val refuelingID: Long = 0L,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "carID")
    val carID: Long = 0L,
)
```

**RefuelingDAO:**

```
@Dao
interface RefuelingDAO
{
    @Query("SELECT * FROM refueling_table ORDER BY refuelingID DESC")
    fun getAll(): LiveData<List<Refueling>>
}
```

**App Database:**

```
@Database(entities = [Car::class, Refueling::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase()
{
    abstract val carDAO: CarDAO
    abstract val refuelingDAO: RefuelingDAO

    companion object
    {
        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE: AppDatabase? = null

        fun getInstance(context: Context): AppDatabase
        {
            synchronized(this)
            {
                var instance = INSTANCE
                if (instance == null)
                {
                    instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                        context.applicationContext,
                        AppDatabase::class.java,
                        "app_database"
                    ).fallbackToDestructiveMigration().build()
                    INSTANCE = instance
                }
                return instance
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Creating ViewModel in fragment:**

```
val arguments = CarFragmentArgs.fromBundle(requireArguments())
val application = requireNotNull(this.activity).application
val dataSource = AppDatabase.getInstance(application).refuelingDAO
val viewModelFactory = CarFragmentVMFactory(dataSource, arguments.carID, application)

viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, viewModelFactory).get(CarFragmentVM::class.java)

binding.carViewModel = viewModel
binding.lifecycleOwner = this
binding.buttonTest.setOnClickListener {
    viewModel.listAll()
}
```

**ViewModel:**

```
class CarFragmentVM(
    private val database: RefuelingDAO,
    private val carID: Long,
    application: Application
) :
        AndroidViewModel(application)
{
    val refueling = database.getAll()
   
    fun listAll()
    {
        refueling.value!!.forEach { \\ IN THIS PLACE I GET ERROR
            Log.d(it)
        }
    }
}
```

When I click on the 'buttonTest' I got `KotlinNullPointerException`. As I said I have the same code in another fragment (I just can't find any differences) and it works fine but this doesn't. Can anyone see where is my problem or give any clue where should I look for it?

Logcat:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.fuelmanager, PID: 22828
    kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException
        at com.example.fuelmanager.ui.car.CarFragmentVM.listAll(CarFragmentVM.kt:44)
        at com.example.fuelmanager.ui.car.CarFragment$onCreateView$1.onClick(CarFragment.kt:44)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7125)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7102)
        at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:801)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27336)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

Line 44 is

```
refueling.value!!.forEach { \\ IN THIS PLACE I GET ERROR
            Log.d(it)
        }
```

Comment: "When I click on the button I got KotlinNullPointerException." -- use Logcat to examine the stack trace. If you do not understand the stack trace, please edit your question and supply the stack trace.

Comment: @CommonsWare okay,  I 'll add but in my code is only one button and I pointed in a code  where exactly I get error

Comment: Yes, but there are many levels in the code that could trigger a `NullPointerException`. As it stands, you are making us guess. **Always provide a stack trace**, whether it is in a Stack Overflow question, a bug report in a GitHub repo, a bug report in JIRA, or anywhere else that you are reporting a crash.

Comment: @CommonsWare Yeah, You are right. I added it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`getAll()` is returning a `LiveData`. The actual database query is being done on a background thread. That will take some time to complete. In the meantime, `value` is `null`. You, however, are assuming that it will complete immediately. So, you try using `value` immediately, and you crash with a `NullPointerException`.

Please `observe()` the `LiveData`.

Comment: Thanks, it is working and that was missing part in my code. But I just can't understand why adding empty observer ` viewModel.refueling.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {})` make this code working. When I click on the button I am trying to get values immediately, like before. Observer only gives me ability to execute a block of code every time LivaData changes but it isn't executed when I click a button.

Comment: @iknow: "But I just can't understand why adding empty observer ` viewModel.refueling.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {})` make this code working" -- that is because it is not working, at least not reliably. Put your logic that uses the `LiveData`-emitted results inside the `Observer`.

Comment: yes, yes, I know and I want to do it after I create RecyclerView like in the previous fragment (that's why I didn't add observer in this fragment because I  didn't have RycaclerView and I just wanted to test database). But at this point adding empty observer `viewModel.refueling.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {})` makes my code working and it is a little strange